# Response without data

Tags: reactjs, cross-domain, fetch

I am getting below response without any data. Could you please help me understand what is "opaque" type response?

```
 componentDidMount() {
     var obj = {
        method: 'GET' ,
        mode : 'no-cors',
        //mode : 'cors', // working
        headers: {
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Authorization',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': ''
        }
    };
     
fetch('<API>', obj)
  //.then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
}
render() {
 console.log(this.state.data);
return (
    <div>App </div>
   )
}
};
 export default App;
```

```
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: 
  false, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: falseredirected: 
  falsestatus: 0statusText: ""type: "opaque"url: ""__proto__: Response
App.js:33 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <API> with MIME type application/json.
```

I need to fetch the data on console from my API from the local server.
But I am getting data in network tab.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the request format?

Comment: Please Share the fetch api call code

Comment: this line `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <API> with MIME type application/json.` makes me think of it as an server configuration problem.

Comment: Please have a look of snippet code..Thanks